# How to handle & identify System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin.forms.listview

I have an Xamarin based APP which uses C#. I have a page `EmployeeProfile`. This page lists all the Employees. There is a API call which provides 10 records at a time. When user scroll down and when last item start to appear, it call for `Loadmore` method which call API for another 10 records.

I use AppCenter to track the errors and crashes. I don't get error when I check with my instance. However, when I check AppCenter crash report, there are lots of crashes on this page.

> Exception: ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException
>   (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource)
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index

Error looks like in `getEmployeeProfile()` method. Can anybody please suggest me which line cause this issue and how can I prevent it? If prevention is not possible, how can I handle it?

Code:

```
publish SearchEmployeeResultsViewModel
{
    public ObservableRangeCollection<EmployeeProfile> SearchEmployee { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeProfile> ListSearchEmployee { get; set; }
    public bool IsNoDataFound { get; set; }
    public int currentPage { get; set; }
    public int recordCount { get; set; }
    public bool IsBusy { get; set; }

    //constructor
    public SearchEmployeeResultsViewModel()
    {
        currentPage = 0;
        recordCount = 10;
        getEmployeeProfile();
    }

    //Call when user scroll down for more EmployeeProfiles
    //Following method call when last item start to visible(ListView event)
    private async Task LoadMore()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await getEmployeeProfile();
        IsBusy = false;
    }

    //Except/Crash raised from here
    private async Task getEmployeeProfile()
    {
        currentPage++;
        //Remove last item if it has no username
        //Purpose: We add blank item at end to manage smooth scrolling while getting next page data
        if (SearchEmployee.Count > 0 && SearchEmployee.Last().UserName == null)
            SearchEmployee.RemoveAt(SearchEmployee.Count() - 1);

        ListSearchEmployee.AddRange((await _profileApiClient.SearchEmployeeCall(currentPage, recordCount)));

        var differenceList = ListSearchEmployee.Except(SearchEmployee).ToList();

        if (differenceList.Count > 0)
        {
            SearchEmployee.AddRange(differenceList);
            //add blank item
            SearchEmployee.Add(new EmployeeProfile());
        }
        IsNoDataFound = (SearchEmployee == null || SearchEmployee.Count() == 0);
    }
}
```

Error Stack Trace:

```
ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource)
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException ()
    List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index)
    Collection`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index)
    ReadOnlyCollection`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index)
    RendererPool.UpdateRenderers (Xamarin.Forms.Element newElement)
    RendererPool.UpdateNewElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
    VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
    VisualElementPackager.OnRendererElementChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs args)
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element)
    IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
    RendererPool.UpdateRenderers (Xamarin.Forms.Element newElement)
    RendererPool.UpdateNewElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
    VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
    VisualElementPackager.OnRendererElementChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs args)
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element)
    IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
    RendererPool.UpdateRenderers (Xamarin.Forms.Element newElement)
    RendererPool.UpdateNewElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
    VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
    VisualElementPackager.OnRendererElementChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs args)
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element)
    IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
    RendererPool.UpdateRenderers (Xamarin.Forms.Element newElement)
    RendererPool.UpdateNewElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
    VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
    VisualElementPackager.OnRendererElementChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs args)
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element)
    IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
    ViewCellRenderer+ViewTableCell.UpdateCell (Xamarin.Forms.ViewCell cell)
    ViewCellRenderer+ViewTableCell.set_ViewCell (Xamarin.Forms.ViewCell value)
    ViewCellRenderer.GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
    CustomViewCellRenderer.GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
    CellTableViewCell.GetNativeCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Xamarin.Forms.Cell cell, System.Boolean recycleCells, System.String templateId)
    ListViewRenderer+ListViewDataSource.GetCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr)
    UITableView.EndUpdates ()
    ListViewRenderer.UpdateItems (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, System.Int32 section, System.Boolean resetWhenGrouped)
    ListViewRenderer.OnCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnProxyCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, System.Boolean fixWindows)
    TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnProxyCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    ListProxy.OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    ListProxy+<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<OnCollectionChanged>b__0 ()
    ListProxy.OnCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    ListProxy+WeakNotifyProxy.OnCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    ObservableCollection`1[T].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    ObservableRangeCollection`1[T].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    ObservableCollection`1[T].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, System.Object item, System.Int32 index)
    ObservableCollection`1[T].InsertItem (System.Int32 index, T item)
    Collection`1[T].Add (T item)
    SearchEmployeeResultsViewModel+<getEmployeeProfile>d__76.MoveNext ()
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
    TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task)
    TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task)
    TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task)
    TaskAwaiter.GetResult ()
    SearchEmployeeResultsViewModel+<LoadMore>d__75.MoveNext ()
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
    AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state)
    UIKitSynchronizationContext+<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 ()
    NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply ()
    (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
    UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate)
    UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
    Application.Main (System.String[] args)
```

Comment: Do you have a complete stack trace? That would make it easier to tell where the problem is.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Yes. I have added

Comment: Looks like it is occurring on `SearchEmployee.Add(new EmployeeProfile());`

Comment: @Igor How can it be possible? I can add new item in the list. List already have atleast 10 item on stage.

Answer (score 1):

> Error looks like in getEmployeeProfile() method. Can anybody please suggest me which line cause this issue....

Based on your stack trace the error is happening on this line:

```
SearchEmployee.Add(new EmployeeProfile());
```

> ... how can I prevent it?

**The cause** appears to be a bound UI control that is trying to iterate over the changed list. For more help you would have to include the design code or code behind that binds to this property. This is based on the top 5 lines in the stack trace you posted.

---

> On the UI side, there is a ListView. ListView binds to SearchEmployee. Is there any way to prevent it or handle it

Looks like a reported bug, see [Bug 59974 - ArgumentOutOfRangeException in listview with ObservableCollection async Updates](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59974).

Comment: On the UI side, there is a ListView. ListView binds to `SearchEmployee`. Is there any way to prevent it or handle it?

Comment: @NanjiMange - See the above update, looks like a reported bug

Comment: How can I prevent this? Is there better way? or I should put a `Task.Delay` of 500 MS? If I nee to put `Task.Delay` where should I put it?(which line)

Comment: @NanjiMange the bug description indicates it might only occur on async methods, could you make it synchronous?

Comment: Okey, let me try. Actually I can get idea whether it is working or not probably after 5-6 day since App is publish to iTunes.

Comment: And is it good idea to call an API without await? Please guide

Comment: @NanjiMange - It depends on how fast the service returns, your app would be unresponsive because the service would block unless you use a background thread to execute that and then resume the UI thread once you have a result.

Comment: Okay, let me publish without async. Let's see the result. Thanks for you time and support.